# Remove dynamically created Items from view in Android

Tags: android, view, tablerow

I have used the following code to create table row

```
TableRow TRow = new TableRow(a);
TextView TxtViewProvider = new TextView(a);
 TxtViewProvider.setText(gradeText);
  // TxtViewProvider.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
  if (bold == 1)
   TxtViewProvider.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
  TxtViewProvider.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
  TxtViewProvider.setPadding(Static.getDipOf(15, a), 0, 0, 0);
 TxtViewProvider.setWidth(getDipOf(240, a));
  TRow.addView(TxtViewProvider);

TxtViewProvider = new TextView(a);
TxtViewProvider.setText(gradeCode);
 TxtViewProvider.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
 if (bold > 0)
   TxtViewProvider.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
  TxtViewProvider.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

  TRow.addView(TxtViewProvider);

  TRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
   params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, Static.getDipOf(1, a));

  table.addView(TRow, params);
```

and i'm using this in a viewflipper but i need to reload this page again and again. But the problem i face is all the data i created first are there when i load it again ,

Can anyone please suggest me a way to remove this dynamically created TableRows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [removeAllViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews%28%29) on the table to remove all the rows and start over.